# Where should font licenses be embedded?

Tags: epub, fonts, license

I am using a font that is licensed under the Open Font License which states:

> 2) Original or Modified Versions of the Font Software may be bundled,
>   redistributed and/or sold with any software, provided that each copy
>   contains the above copyright notice and this license. These can be
>   included either as stand-alone text files, human-readable headers or
>   in the appropriate machine-readable metadata fields within text or
>   binary files as long as those fields can be easily viewed by the user.

Where can I place this license file in my EPUB where it complies with the license requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't disagree with the above answer.

I just wanted to say that on the Title/Credits HTML page (which contains copyright, date, etc) I included this line:

The HomemadeApple Font embedded in this ebook is copyrighted 2010 by Font Diner, Inc. under a Apache 2.0 license.  (and I linked to the license).

Answer (score 2):

As the license requirements state "easily viewed by the user" you should include the full license in the EPUB zip files META-INF directory as e.g. `open_font_license.txt`, in addition to that add a stanza:

```
 <dc:license>Open Font Software distributed as per open_font_license.txt</dc:license>
```

to the `META-INF/metadata.opf` file.

The latter should show up when viewing the metadata info in EPUB readers. If
the copyright text is short, you can forego the `open_font_license.txt` file and directly include everything in the `metadata.opf` stanza.

Comment: Does it need to be `META-INF/metadata.opf`? I am using Sigil to build my ebook and it doesn't have a `metadata.opf` in `META-INF`. But there is `OEBPS/content.opf`which contains a `<metadata>` tag and in it are elements like `<dc:language>en</dc:language>`. Could I place it there?

Comment: @Keavon Probably yes. Make sure to check afterwards in an epub viewer (e.g. the one from Calibre) that the information shows up when you click "Show book metadata")

Answer (score 1):

As I had not seen this question, I have asked [another one](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2844/5047) very similar somewhere else.

I have tested the solution proposed by Anthon, but the addition of a `<dc:license>` element into the `content.opf` is unfortunaltely pointed as an error when checking the file with Sigil and FlightCrew:

> Error XML child not recognized: the `<licence>` element is not an allowed child of the `<metadata>` element

Consequently, I opted for [an alternate method](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2859/5047) for embedding such a license file, by creating an `ofl.xhtml` file using the `copyright-page` guide element.

This method has also the advantage to grant an easy access to the license text (especially if a specific line is added in the `title.xhtml`, as pointed by idiotprogrammer)